# Make section font all caps

Tags: sectioning, small-caps, sectsty

I am using the following code with `sectsty` to make all sections use small caps:

```
\sectionfont{\sc}
```

However, I want them all typesetted in lowercase, but the following does not work:

```
\sectionfont{\MakeLowercase\sc}
```

Comment: Why not use `\MakeUppercase`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since `\MakeLowercase` takes an argument, try flipping around your macros:

```
\sectionfont{\sc\MakeLowercase}
```

You should also use `\scshape` instead of `\sc`.

Comment: Thank you. Any special reason to use `\scshape` instead of `\sc` ?

Comment: Using the old TeX-style commands to switch fonts doesn't support LaTeX's new font selection scheme (NFSS). So using `\sc` would cancel out `\bf`, for instance, whereas `\scshape` would be applied in addition to a `\bfseries` (i.e., you can apply multiple font commands simultaneously).  Compare with the following code: `{\bf bold \it italics} {\bfseries bold \itshape and italics}`.